# Attempting to get data from various groups in the regex fails

Tags: java, regex, indexoutofboundsexception, regex-group

I have the following regex to look for emails in a string(there might be 0 or more emails in the string).The expression has 4 groups,some of which could match a null value:

[RegexPlanet Test](http://fiddle.re/m3m6r) for the expression:

```
          ([-A-Za-z0-9._!#$%^&*|{}'~`]+@[a-z0-9_-]+[\\.][a-z]{2,3}[\\.][a-z]{2,3})|([A-Za-z0-9.!#$%^&*|{}\"~`]+@[a-z0-9_-]+[\\.][a-z]{4})|([A-Z.a-z0-9!#$%^&*|{}'~`]+@[a-z0-9_-]+[\\.][a-z]{3})|([A-Za-z0-9.!#$%^&*_-|{}'~`]+@[a-z0-9_-]+[\\.][a-z]{2})
```

The code to read the data from the matcher shows an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` at `matchValue=matcher.group(i);`

```
   ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(input);
    Log.d(TAG,"input: "+input);
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        String matchValue=null;
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
        {
            matchValue=matcher.group(i);
            if(matchValue!=null && !matchValue.equals(""))
            {    
                Log.d(TAG, "Group no: "+i+" Value: "+matchValue+" adding to result");
                result.add(matchValue);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Nothing matched for group i");
            }
        }    
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code or is this a side-effect of something else?

Thanking you in advance for your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i=1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++)
{
    matchValue=matcher.group(i);
    ...
```

I am not sure why you would have a problem with the code you have, it seems to have exactly four groups, so `for(int i=1; i<5;` seems correct.  But it is better to have the matcher tell you what the count is.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing at the same time as user1631616 :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what input causes the exception?
In general to avoid this exception you can rewrite `for` loop as this:

```
for(int i=1;i<=matcher.groupCount();i++)
        {....}
```